# Rearrange a symbolic function in order that the result contains a minimum number of SQRT() and CBRT() calculations

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, c-codegenerator

I use mathematica for analytically calculating a function, which solves two equations:

```
eqn = Power[R id - om Lq iq, 2] + Power[R iq + om Ld id + om Psi, 2] - 
Umax Umax == 0 /. iq -> 2 M/(3  Np (Psi + (Ld - Lq) id))

solutions = Solve[eqn, id];
```

This gives 4 solutions, which are very long (hundreds of lines), so I will not write them here. 
I need only two of those solutions. By evaluating the funtions for different arguments I check, which are the correct ones. E.g.:

```
desiredSolution = id /. solutions[[1]];
```

with

```
LeafCount[desiredSolution]
(*69425*)
```

I have to implement the two solutions as C code which should run on a microcontroller. 
Therefore and as next step, I tried to automatically simplify the expression together with the assumptions

```
{M, om, R, Ld, Lq, Psi, Umax} > 0   and   Lq > Ld
```

using `Simplify[]` or `FullSimplify[]`, but this did not lead to a result.

Since this seemed to be a dead-end road, I used my own `cform[]`

```
Remove["cform"]
cform[Rational[a_,b_]]:=cform[N[a/b,20]]/;NumericQ[a]&&NumericQ[b];
cform[Rational[a_,b_]]:=cform[a]<>"/"<>cform[b]<>"";
cform[Times[a_,b_]]:=cform[a]<>" * "<>cform[b] ;
cform[Plus[a_,b_]]:="("<>cform[a]<>" + "<>cform[b]<>")";
cform[Plus[a_,Times[-1,b_]]]:=cform[a] <> " - " <> cform[b];
cform[Times[-1,b_]]:= " - " <> cform[b];
cform[Power[a_,1]]:=cform[a] ;
cform[Power[a_,2]]:=cform[a]<>"*"<>cform[a];
cform[Power[a_,b_]]:="1/" <> cform[Power[a,-b]]/;b<0;
cform[Power[a_,1/2]]:="SQRT(" <> cform[a] <> ")";
cform[Power[a_,1/3]]:="CBRT(" <> cform[a] <> ")";
cform[a_?AtomQ]:=ToString[a];
cform[h_[args__]]:=cform[h]<>"("<>StringJoin[Riffle[cform/@{args},","]]<>")";
```

together with `Experimental'OptimizeExpression`

```
Remove["x*"];
ccode=Module[{out},out=Experimental`OptimizeExpression[desiredSolution,"OptimizationSymbol"->x,OptimizationLevel->2]/.HoldPattern[Experimental`OptimizedExpression[Block[{tempVars__},CompoundExpression[defs:Set[_,_]...,expr_]]]]:>Block[{Set="stdCType " <> ToString[#1]<>" = "<>ToString[cform[#2]]<> ";" & },List[defs,expr]];
{"void cfun(){",Most@out,"result = "<>ToString@cform@Last@out <> ";","}"}]//Flatten//ExportString[#,"Table"]&
```

to optimize the expression and generate C code from it. In order to have the correct data type (an arbitrary floating point type "tf") used in each calculation, I applied some further rules:

```
    regEx = RegularExpression[
   "(([0-9]+[.]+[0-9]*)|([0-9]*[.]+[0-9]+))[+,-,*,/,;,\\s]+(?!=)"];
repRule1[string_] := 
 StringReplace[string, 
  x : RegularExpression["(?<![0-9,a-z,.])[0-9]+(?![0-9,a-z,.])"] :>  
   StringReplace[x, 
    y : RegularExpression[ "[0-9]+"] :> "(tf)" <> y <> ""]]
repRule2[string_] := 
 StringReplace[string, 
  x : regEx :>  StringReplace[x, y : regEx :> "(tf)" <> y]]
repRule3[string_] := 
  StringReplace[
   string, {"SQRT((tf)2)" ->  "SQRT_2", "CBRT((tf)2)" ->  "CBRT_2"}];
repRule[string_] := repRule3[repRule2[repRule1[string <> " "]]];
ccode2 = repRule[ccode]
```

The outcome contains (as it should be) only the basic math operations `+, -, *, /` as well as `SQRT()` and `CBRT()` functions, which can be computed on the microcontroller as well. It looks as follows:

```
tf cfun(){
   tf x4 =  - Lq;
   tf x5 = (Ld + x4);

   ...

   tf x147 = -(tf)0.25000000000000000000 * x145 * x146;
   tf x148 = (x126 + (x127 + (x128 + (x129 + (x147 + x44)))));
   tf x149 = SQRT(x148);
   return (-(tf)0.50000000000000000000 * x124 + (-(tf)0.50000000000000000000 * x149 + -(tf)0.50000000000000000000 * x14 * x20 * x6));
}
```

For this equation (I need calculations of some more and similar solutions) this yields in following numbers of necessary mathematical calculations on the microcontroller:

```
"+ / -" <> " --> " <> ToString[StringCount[ccode2, {"+","-"}]]
"* / /" <> " --> " <> ToString[StringCount[ccode2, {"*","/"}]]
"SQRT" <> " --> " <> ToString[StringCount[ccode2, "SQRT"]]
"CBRT" <> " --> " <> ToString[StringCount[ccode2, "CBRT"]]
(* + / - --> 119 *)
(* * / / --> 349
(* SQRT --> 3 *)
(* CBRT --> 2 (where one is CBRT(2) that is replaced by a constant)) *)
```

In general, the procedure is working and the generated C code is giving correct results on the microcontroller.
However, since I "only" used the automatic optimization `Experimental'OptimizeExpression` to simplify the calculation, I'm not sure, whether this is the best solution in terms of needed calculation time. The calculation time is very important for my application. It would be benefical, to have as less `SQRT()` and `CBRT()` operations in the C code.

What do you think about my process? Can you give me suggestions how it could be possible, to further improve the outcome in terms of the necessary number of `SQRT()` and `CBRT()` calculations resp. the necessary calculation time?

Furthermore I did not manage to apply `Experimental'OptimizeExpression` on multiple equations simultaneously until now. On this way I would like to collect common terms of all my equations to further reduce the overall count of mathematical operations that are executed in the microcontroller. How is this possible?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to solve them numerically e.g. using standard root-finding code, once given values for the parameters? Even if you manage to code the symbolic solution, numeric evaluation might be quite unstable. And it is not certain that the two symbolic roots you choose will be the correct ones once instantiated with numeric values for the parameters.

Comment: I'm not deeply informed about possibilities using root-finding algorithms, but one important requirement is a deterministic and predetermined behavior of the algorithm, especially in terms of calculation time. 
So I have no idea, whether such solution yould yield better results. It would be great if you could recommend some "specific" agorithm for my specific problems, in order that I could inform myself more easily.

Comment: The nummerical stability seemed to be good in firsts tests and under the tested input parameter variations. Clearly this is no proof for overall stability yet. The same holds for the selection of the correct roots. Under the tested parameter variations, the correct solution was always obtained using the selected solutions.

Comment: Maybe for your purposes this is best. As for using fewer square and cube roots, clearly it cannot be reduced by much and I doubt it can be reduced at all. Note however that solving quartics in radicals involve solving cubics, and that can get one into the casus irreducibilis if two of the cubic roots are complex valued. The implication is that the numerical code might produce complex values, which ultimately cancel. But the C code might get into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your hints regarding the basic method. I don't want to comment them, since I can't really estimate whether another approach would be more usefull for my speecific problem. I think I would need more time first to get myself informed.

I think that (at least the actual C code) can be reduced in terms of necessary calculation power since my actual final and automatically calculated code still contains a lot of duplicate calculations. However, I don't know yet, how I could identify them resp. do this automatically.

Comment: I tried two ways now:
1. Used Experimental'OptimizeExpression for each of the equations separately --> Outcome: Duplicate calculations, since the result of Experimental'OptimizeExpression for the second equation does not consider the Experimental'OptimizeExpression for the first equation and so on.
2. Used Experimental'OptimizeExpression for all equations at the same time.
Method 2 did not really seem to give better results in terms of the number of the calculations. I have no idea why.